# Catel Example Orc Wizard - How to size the Wizard window

Tags: resize, catel

Trying to learn Catel. Looking at the Orc.Wizard.Example.NET40 application. I cannot figure out how to set the size of the Wizard window. For example, the sample code seems to produce a default sized window for the wizard. Where does this default come from? How can I change it?
The "MainView" window size can be changed in "MainView.xaml" but what about the window size of the Wizard itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [WizardBase](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Wizard/blob/develop/src/Orc.Wizard/Orc.Wizard.Shared/Models/WizardBase.cs#L46), it has a default size of 650 x 500. You can customize the size of the wizard in your `Wizard` implementation.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did: 
`public MyOwnFirstWizard(ITypeFactory typeFactory) : base(typeFactory){`  
`MinSize = new System.Windows.Size(0.75 * System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, 0.80 * System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);`  
`MaxSize = new System.Windows.Size(0.75 * System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, 0.80 * System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);`  
`AddPage<WizardStep1>();`  
`...`
I like Catel!